# Jasmine - how to test for values which are not being returned by actual function during testing?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How can I test for values / return values for testing purposes in my test which I don't return in my actual function?

```
    function testing(one,two,three){
      var result;
      var add=one+two;
      var subtr=three-two;
      result=one+add+subtr;
      return result;
    }
    testing(5,10,4)
```

if I wanted to test the result, I would do this:

```
            describe("calculate numbers", function() {
              it("result should add all three arguments", function() {
                var final = testing(5,10,4);
                expect(final).toEqual(14);
              });
            })
```

but how can I test for things I don't return in my function? How can I test for example 'add' or 'subtle' so for add say it should return 15. Can I return other values during testing which I don't return in my actual function?

Answer (score 0):

When you find something hard to unit test regardless the programming language, it indicates a possible smell in the code's architecture. Write tests first, and only then the code if you want to have easy-to-test code, aka TDD.

On one hand, simple solution would be to split your function into several smaller functions and test them separately. This way you are not violating Single Responsibility Principle (SRP).

However on the other hand, if your logic in the function is trivial and you only care about the final result, then test the final result only, i.e. test WHAT the code should return rather than HOW it should return it.

In real life situations, I tend to break functions into smaller ones and wrap them in data services, and unit-test the data service.